# Storing objects as variables in a PHP class

Tags: php, oop

Assume you have several arbitrary classes like below:

```
class Foo
{
    $foovar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $foovar = "Foo";
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        return($foovar);
    }
}

class Bar
{
    $F;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $F = new Foo();
    }
}
```

My question is is it possible to write something like the following

```
$B = new Bar();
echo($B->F->getFoo());
```

Like I said in my previous question, I come from a strong Java background know you can link variables together `System.out.println()` to call other objects methods. I'd like to know if this is possible in PHP

Comment: Your example is storing an *object* (a class instance), not a *class*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're absolutely correct, please see this example.

```
class Foo {
 public function hello() {
  return 'hello world';
 }
}

class Bar {
 public $driver = NULL;

 public function __construct() {
  $this->driver = new Foo;
 }
}

$test = new Bar;
echo $test->driver->hello();
```

Some other comments

```
return($foovar);
```

- The parens aren't needed here.
- You must use `$this->foovar`  to work with class members (unless static, in which case it's `self::$foovar`

Class members must also have their access type specifed, for example `public $foovar;`.

Why you're moving from Java to PHP is beyond me, but good luck :)

Comment: Moving because Java is great, but for a lot of the Web development I'm doing PHP fits the bill perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It most certainly is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it possible but it is very common. One time you will see it used is with [delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

If the `$F` in `$B` is public or you have a `__get($var)` method in Bar that is willing to return `$F` then `$B->F->getFoo()` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but with some additional syntax.  I used the getter methods to hopefully illustrate things a little better, but they aren't needed if you make your variables in the class public.

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    private $foovar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foovar = "Foo";
    }

    public function getFooVar()
    {
        return $this->foovar;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    private $fooclass;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fooclass = new Foo();
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->fooclass;
    }
}


$bar = new Bar();
print $bar->getFoo()->getFooVar();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible 
Its called chaining methods

```
// first clean your code 

class Foo
{
    public $foovar = NULL; 

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foovar = "Foo";
        return $this;
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->foovar;
    }
}

class Bar
{
    public $F = NULL;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->F = new Foo();
        return $this;
    }
}

$B  = new Bar(); // create the object. The constructor returns the whole object
// so we have full access to the methods
// firs call the object $B which return in the constructor $this so we call now 
// method F now the object F returns also in the constructor the whole object $this
// we now can access the method getFoo() which will print Foo
echo $B->F->getFoo();
```

Comment: Why are you setting $foovar to NULL at the beginning?

Comment: Because i init all vars to a default value; Its not neccesary but i do